# Monaco-Editor Single String From Database

Tags: html, layout, line-breaks, monaco-editor

Been researching for the last couple of days and still no result. I have a back-end database that saves text entered in the Monaco-Editor. However, text will not display/load if there are new line returns (\r\n) in the string. The only I can get the text to display is to remove the line returns.

Here is some client-side code.

```
<div id="container" style="width:590px;height:400px;border:1px solid grey;white-space:pre-wrap;"></div>
//saving to hidden value
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="editorValue" />

   require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' } });

require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
    var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), { 
        value: ['<%=MyJSText%>'].join('\n'),
        language: 'javascript'           
    });

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {         
        jQuery("#<%=linkOK.ClientID%>").on('click', function () {
        getVal = editor.getValue();
        document.getElementById("<%=editorValue.ClientID%>").value = getVal;
        });
    });
```

Some server side code

```
protected string MyJSText
    {
        get
        {
            if (EnableIDEditor)
            {

                return Server.HtmlDecode(TemplateRevision.JsScripts.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "));

            }
            else 
            {
                return Server.HtmlDecode(TemplateRevision.JsScripts);
            }                    

        }
    }
```

I'd like the text entered into the monaco-editor box to display with line-breaks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem by adding the following code on the server-side.

```
 protected string MyJSText
    {
        get
        {
            if (EnableIDEditor)
            {                    
                return Server.HtmlDecode(TemplateRevision?.JsScripts?.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\\\r\\n"));                    
            }
            else 
            {
                return Server.HtmlDecode(TemplateRevision.JsScripts);
            }                    

        }
    }
```

The trick was to use .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\\r\n")) and the line breaks showed appropriately. Hope this helps someone who is looking to dynamically insert text into the monaco-editor.